# Question too broad - feedback issue

Tags: discussion, needs-more-focus

After seeing the following links:

[Data modal design for structured interviewing SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50127021/data-modal-design-for-structured-interviewing)

[Data modal design for structured interviewing CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/193418/data-modal-design-for-structured-interviewing)

[Data modal design for structured interviewing DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205521/data-modal-design-for-structured-interviewing)

I have the distinct feeling that:

- the question is doomed to be marked off-topic on DBA pretty soon, given the questions asked at the bottom (maybe even with the reason that this belongs to SO)
- After that happpens, the OP is unlikely to ask another question soon on SO (or any SE site, for that matter)
- The question was originally asked on SO, and somehow, it could've been handled differently

The question is: should this question have been handled differently? If so, how?

Comment: I always tell OP to read the help center of suggested site before posting there.. Not sure if it would have helped in this case

Comment: @SurajRao I do the same, but I'm increasingly thinking that it's not helping new users as much as we'd like. I guess to them it feels like they're being handed a big rulebook - and not even a guarantee that they CAN post after reading it all!

Comment: Did the OP just repost it to DBA on their own initiative, or did SO point them?

Comment: Oh, never mind,.  After opening the links, it's apparent that this Q has been passed around like a ticking parcel.  I have been saying for some time that SO users should not recommend or migrate to any other sites.  I close as off-topic and comment 'This MAY be on-topic at DBA, but check out their rules/policy first'.  The OP sees '....................DBA...................'.

Comment: @MartinJames from the looks of it OP went from SO to CodeReview and from there to dba each because of a comment

Comment: @SurajRao yeah - passed on like a grenade with the pin out.

Comment: Loking at the actual body of the question, SO should have just destroyed it with a controlled explosion.

Comment: SO should make it policy to not recommend any other sites if an off-topic question is posted on SO, just close it.  Understandably, DBA, and the other SE sites, don't want [unwelcome word] questions directed their way.   This is an example of SO being 'too welcoming' :(